# Restricting Page for Non-Logged In Users Without PHP

Tags: javascript, html, authentication, oauth, azure-active-directory

I am currently working on a project that allows users to authenicate their logins with our Microsoft work/school accounts. Currently, I have a page where the user calls the API to login, like this:

```js
// Graph API endpoint to show user profile
var graphApiEndpoint = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me";

// Graph API scope used to obtain the access token to read user profile
var graphAPIScopes = ["https://graph.microsoft.com/user.read"];

// Initialize application
var userAgentApplication = new Msal.UserAgentApplication(msalconfig.clientID, null, loginCallback, {
    redirectUri: msalconfig.redirectUri
});

//Previous version of msal uses redirect url via a property
if (userAgentApplication.redirectUri) {
    userAgentApplication.redirectUri = msalconfig.redirectUri;
}

window.onload = function () {
    // If page is refreshed, continue to display user info
    if (!userAgentApplication.isCallback(window.location.hash) && window.parent === window && !window.opener) {
        var user = userAgentApplication.getUser();
        if (user) {
            callGraphApi();
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Call the Microsoft Graph API and display the results on the page. Sign the user in if necessary
 */
function callGraphApi() {
    var user = userAgentApplication.getUser();
    if (!user) {
        // If user is not signed in, then prompt user to sign in via loginRedirect.
        // This will redirect user to the Azure Active Directory v2 Endpoint
        userAgentApplication.loginRedirect(graphAPIScopes);
        // The call to loginRedirect above frontloads the consent to query Graph API during the sign-in.
        // If you want to use dynamic consent, just remove the graphAPIScopes from loginRedirect call.
        // As such, user will be prompted to give consent when requested access to a resource that 
        // he/she hasn't consented before. In the case of this application - 
        // the first time the Graph API call to obtain user's profile is executed.
    } else {
        // If user is already signed in, display the user info
        window.location = "calc.html"
        
    }
}

/**
 * Callback method from sign-in: if no errors, call callGraphApi() to show results.
 * @param {string} errorDesc - If error occur, the error message
 * @param {object} token - The token received from login
 * @param {object} error - The error string
 * @param {string} tokenType - The token type: For loginRedirect, tokenType = "id_token". For acquireTokenRedirect, tokenType:"access_token".
 */
function loginCallback(errorDesc, token, error, tokenType) {
    if (errorDesc) {
        showError(msal.authority, error, errorDesc);
    } else {
        callGraphApi();
    }
}

/**
 * Show an error message in the page
 * @param {string} endpoint - the endpoint used for the error message
 * @param {string} error - Error string
 * @param {string} errorDesc - Error description
 */
function showError(endpoint, error, errorDesc) {
    var formattedError = JSON.stringify(error, null, 4);
    if (formattedError.length < 3) {
        formattedError = error;
    }
    document.getElementById("errorMessage").innerHTML = "An error has occurred:<br/>Endpoint: " + endpoint + "<br/>Error: " + formattedError + "<br/>" + errorDesc;
    console.error(error);
}

/**
 * Call a Web API using an access token.
 * @param {any} endpoint - Web API endpoint
 * @param {any} token - Access token
 * @param {object} responseElement - HTML element used to display the results
 * @param {object} showTokenElement = HTML element used to display the RAW access token
 */
function callWebApiWithToken(endpoint, token, responseElement, showTokenElement) {
    var headers = new Headers();
    var bearer = "Bearer " + token;
    headers.append("Authorization", bearer);
    var options = {
        method: "GET",
        headers: headers
    };

    fetch(endpoint, options)
        .then(function (response) {
            var contentType = response.headers.get("content-type");
            if (response.status === 200 && contentType && contentType.indexOf("application/json") !== -1) {
                response.json()
                    .then(function (data) {
                        // Display response in the page
                        console.log(data);
                        responseElement.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data, null, 4);
                        if (showTokenElement) {
                            showTokenElement.parentElement.classList.remove("hidden");
                            showTokenElement.innerHTML = token;
                        }
                    })
                    .catch(function (error) {
                        showError(endpoint, error);
                    });
            } else {
                response.json()
                    .then(function (data) {
                        // Display response as error in the page
                        showError(endpoint, data);
                    })
                    .catch(function (error) {
                        showError(endpoint, error);
                    });
            }
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            showError(endpoint, error);
        });
}

/**
 * Sign-out the user
 */
function signOut() {
    userAgentApplication.logout();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- bootstrap reference used for styling the page -->
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Home</title>


</head>
<body style="margin: 40px">
    <button id="callGraphButton" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="callGraphApi()">Call Microsoft Graph API</button>
    <div id="errorMessage" class="text-danger"></div>
    <div class="hidden">
        <h3>Graph API Call Response</h3>
        <pre class="well" id="graphResponse"></pre>
    </div>
    <div class="hidden">
        <h3>Access Token</h3>
        <pre class="well" id="accessToken"></pre>
    </div>
    <div class="hidden">
        <h3>ID Token Claims</h3>
        <pre class="well" id="userInfo"></pre>
    </div>
    <button id="signOutButton" type="button" class="btn btn-primary hidden" onclick="signOut()">Sign out</button>

    <script src="https://secure.aadcdn.microsoftonline-p.com/lib/0.1.3/js/msal.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bluebird/3.3.4/bluebird.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fetch/2.0.3/fetch.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="msalconfig.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The page is also connected to an msalconfig file, but I will not include said file for security reasons, since it contains some tokens.

If the user is logged in successfully, he/she is routed to calc.html, a simple caluclator app I've designed for testing purposes only. However, at the moment, anyone could access the calc.html file if they went to the URL. I want a way to only allow signed in users to access the page, as in the end, the project will allow various professors and others at my institution to change the scheudles for their courses over a ten-year period. Is there a way to do this without PHP? If so, what do these ways look like? I would prefer to keep things web based and client side if possible, but am open to anything.

Comment: Use a form and validate it with JavaScript, then pass a unique key to the `calc.html` page and validate that

Comment: How do you recommend passing the key from the index page to the calc page? @JBDouble05

Comment: How are you planning to store the schedule data? It would seem you need a server-side component for that in any case, so adding a server-side component that checks credentials before delivering the static app components might not be that big a hurdle.

Comment: You could use NodeJS maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite an open-ended question, but I'll take a stab at it.

First, you state that you're not willing to share `msaclconfig.js` -- and I quite understand if you don't wish to share it to Stack Overflow. However, you are sharing that file to anyone who happens to load your login page. That could be completely anyone.

For the use case you stated -- multiple people editing and viewing a same set of data -- you will need a server-side component. However, you don't necessarily need to create or host that component yourself. As you're using Microsoft's services for authentication already, maybe you could use their services for data storage as well? For example, the Graph API prominently advertises that it can access Excel, and that might work as storage backend.

If you are using Microsoft's services for both authentication and data storage, non-authorized user loading the application page might not be an issue. They can see the page itself, but thay can't see or edit the schedule -- provided that the permissions to see and edit the backing data storage are suitably set up, of course. This is, of course, a security tradeoff. Seeing the app helps a potential attacker, but this can be acceptable if the server is secure enough.

Similar thing applies to any storage backend you might use. At authentication, some sort of authentication token is generated. This should be something such that only the server is able to generate valid tokens, and that the server can later check that the token it received from client is valid. At every request to data storage, that token is checked, and data is accessed only with a valid token. Seeing the static app page might not be an issue, as the actual sensitive contents are only delivered to authenticated and authorized users.